# Push Win VM Security log events to Az Monitor

Tags: azure-monitoring

Is there any guidance available specifically for capturing Windows event logs from Az VMs in Az Monitor?  I’d like to capture successful login events from the Security log across 30 VMs in Az Monitor.  So far I’ve enabled each VM in it’s diagnostic settings blade, but I’m less clear on how to find and filter the data in Azure Monitor.

Thanks 
Mark